# Should credentials be passed in HTTP header or in body?

Tags: http, asp.net-web-api

I am working with ASP.Net Web API and landed into this question:

Should credentials be passed in HTTP header or in body? Why?

Answer (score 0):

You should use the Authorization header.

In some cases, you MAY find credentials in the body, such as in OAuth, as described in the following RFC, but it is not a recommended practice:

https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6749#section-2.3.1

The reason why it should be in the dedicated header, is simply because it is what the standards and RFCs recommend. If you encounter another more specific RFC or documentation that says otherwise, then you should follow what the RFC / documentation says, simple as that :)